# She and I are in different cities or she and I are in a different city

Tags: grammar, singular-vs-plural

> She and I are in different cities
>
> She and I are in a different city

Which sentence is correct? I intuitively chose the first one until I saw the [lyrics](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&rlz=1C1CHBF_enSG763SG763&biw=1517&bih=694&sxsrf=ALeKk01dH98dbyYjTJyidJdmEukzhBCAmg%3A1590592730710&ei=2oTOXr3zKoOnoAS3-ZK4DA&q=good%20as%20gold%20natty%20reeves%20lyrics&oq=good%20as%20gold%20nat&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAxgBMgIIADICCAAyBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB46BAgAEEc6BAgjECc6BQgAEJECOggIABCRAhCLAzoFCAAQiwM6BwgjEOoCECc6BAgAEEM6BwgAEEMQiwM6CggAEBQQhwIQiwM6BAgAEAo6CAgAEBYQChAeOgcIABAUEIcCUOmaBliR6AZg3foGaARwA3gAgAHHAogB8COSAQYyLTE3LjGYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6sAEKuAEC&sclient=psy-ab) of the song 'Good as Gold'

> My heart your heart run a different race
>
> My voice your voice sing a different song

Comment: ***Never*** use song lyrics or newspaper headlines to help you understand English syntax!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They actually have two different meanings.

- The first one: "**She and I are in different cities**" means she is in a different city than yours. Just replace She and I with We: "We are in different cities."
- The second one: "**She and I  are in a different city.**" means you are in a different city with her, as opposed to others. Again if we use We: "We are in a different city."

Comment: Song lyrics tend to follow their own rules rather than grammatical ones.

Comment: True indeed.That's why I didn't make any comments on the song, since it might have the aforementioned two meanings.